# Python Virtual Environment Deployment Automation

Tags: python, .net, pipeline, virtual-environment

We have a .NET app that uses a Python module through the use of an instance of System.Diagnostics.Process. This is the first time that we are leveraging Python in this way. What are some of the best methods for automating the creation of our virtual environment both on Devs' local machines and on deployment to our build servers?

I tried to reference the Python project from our C# project, thinking that it might automatically create the virtual environment upon build, but it does not work that way and cannot even handle the reference to the Python project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.